# Combining scss files into one with imports

Tags: sass

If I want to split my scss into multiple files, does every file need an import statement.

Eg if I have

- _variables.scss,
- Header.scss
- Footer.scss
- Content.scss

Will the (bottom) 3 files require imports in them  (if they're using variables)
I want to have a final file eg Site.scss that merges the 3 with imports

or should the variables imports go in Site.scss too?

Answer (score 2):

In your Site.scss file, import the `_variables.scss` at the top and all other files below it

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'Header';
@import 'Footer';
@import 'Content';
```

That way all other files can use the variables. You don't need to include `_variables.scss` in every other files.

Answer (score 1):

Every file needs an import statement, but they can all be in the root file.

Here's a great little tutorial that I've been following to make it work:

[How to Structure a SASS Project](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project)